# C++ MSVCP120D.dlll is missing from your computer error VS2017

Tags: c++

```
/*******************************************************************
*    PURPOSE:     To compute Pascal's triangle and illustrate
*                 the use of the debugger.
*    PROGRAMMER:  Leslie Foster
*    REMARKS:     The code below is chosen to illustrate the debugger.
*                 It is neither the most efficient nor the most reliable
*                 way to solve this problem.
*
* From Computing Concepts with C++ Essentials, 3rd ed., Cay S. Horstmann
*************************************************************************/


#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
 using namespace std;

/*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

void skip(int n)
/*  PURPOSE:  To skip n spaces on a line
RECEIVES: n - the number of spaces to skip
REMARKS:  n should be non-negative
*/
{
    int i;  /* a counter */

    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        cout << " ";
}
/*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

int factorial(int n)
/*  PURPOSE:  To calculate n factorial
RECEIVES: n - calculate the factorial of n
RETURNS:  n factorial
REMARKS:  n must be >= 0.  Also if n is too large overflow may result
*/
{
    int  product; /*  accumulator for the running product  */
    int  i; /*  a counter  */

    product = 1;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        product = product + i;
    }
    return(product);
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

int combination(int n, int k)
/* PURPOSE:  to calculate the number of combinations of n things taken
k at a time (n choose k)
RECEIVES: n - the number of items to choose from
k - the number of items choosen
RETURNS:  n choose k
REMARKS:  n and k must be non-negative and k <= n.  This program uses
the formula (n choose k) = n! / ( k! * (n-k)! ).
*/
{
    int comb = factorial(n) / factorial(k) * factorial(n - k);

    return comb;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

int main(void)
{
    int nrows; /*  the number of rows to print  */
    int n; /*  a counter for the current row  */
    int k; /*  a counter for the current column  */
    int comb; /*  the number of combinations  */
    int spaces_to_skip; /*  spaces to skip  */

    cout << "Enter the number of rows (<=13) in Pascal's triangle: ";
    cin >> nrows;
    cout << "\n\n\n";

    /*  print the title  * /
    skip(16);
    cout << "TABLE 1: THE FIRST " << nrows << " ROWS OF PASCAL'S 
TRIANGLE\n\n";

    / *  start a loop over the number of rows  */
    spaces_to_skip = 36;

    for (n = 0; n < nrows; n = n + 2)
{
    skip(spaces_to_skip); /* space to make a triangle */
    spaces_to_skip = spaces_to_skip - 2;

    for (k = 0; k <= n; k++)
    {
        comb = combination(n, k);
        cout << setw(4) << comb;
    }

    cout << "\n";
}

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

I have been trying to solve this error for quite a while, I have already tried downloading the MSVCP120D.dlll files online, both 32 bit and 64 bit. I have already tried putting the 32 bit file into System32 file and the 64 bit file into SysWOW64 file, but this does not solve the error. Any form of help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

MSVCP120**D**.dll is part of a **debug** C/C++ runtime. You get a dependency on that library in debug builds only. Generally, you are not supposed to be distributing debug builds, and therefore you wouldn't need that library.

If you make a release build, it will depend on MSVCP120.dll, which you can get by installing the [Visual Studio redistributable package](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=40784). Note that MSVCP120.dll is part of Visual Studio 2013 rather than 2017 that you mention, so I am linking the VS2013 version. Apart from that, Microsoft bundles these DLLs as part of the Visual Studio installation, in case you want to distribute them with your software. On my machine, these are located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\redist\x64\Microsoft.VC120.CRT`. With newer versions of Visual Studio, you just drop those DLLs next to your executable. With earlier versions, you would put the containing folder, that is `Microsoft.VC???.CRT` next to your executable.

Finally, even though you are not supposed to redistribute the debug CRT DLLs, Microsoft still includes them as part of the Visual Studio installation. On my machine, they are in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x64\Microsoft.VC120.DebugCRT`